# Draw extra upper/lower limit in ListViewMultiChartActivity

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I have download MPAndroidChart Example in order to make some changes so I decide to change
ListViewMultiChartActivity and in LineChartItem I add upper/lower limit and run applications and it is working but when I scroll down, in linechart is added other upper/lower limits that I do not create and it is strange. I added some image and a code

I am using Android Studio and Android 8.0 API 26 and mpandroidchart 3.1.0-alpha
That only happen when I scroll down faster but If I scroll slower it is not happen. The problem that I see is that upper/lower limit are belong to other line graph and in one graph is overlaping.

https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/34872326/50542025-3ede8280-0b80-11e9-9463-1153a26caa0d.jpg

https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/34872326/50542022-3e45ec00-0b80-11e9-9c75-d9f15634bac4.jpg

```
holder.chart.getDescription().setEnabled(false);
holder.chart.setDrawGridBackground(false);

XAxis xAxis = holder.chart.getXAxis();
xAxis.setPosition(XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
xAxis.setTypeface(mTf);
xAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
xAxis.setDrawAxisLine(true);

YAxis leftAxis = holder.chart.getAxisLeft();
leftAxis.setTypeface(mTf);
leftAxis.setLabelCount(5, false);
leftAxis.setAxisMinimum(0f); // this replaces setStartAtZero(true)

YAxis rightAxis = holder.chart.getAxisRight();
rightAxis.setTypeface(mTf);
rightAxis.setLabelCount(5, false);
rightAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
rightAxis.setAxisMinimum(0f); // this replaces setStartAtZero(true)


LimitLine upper_limit = new LimitLine(mChartData.getYMax(), "Max Value");
upper_limit.setLineWidth(2f);
upper_limit.enableDashedLine(10f, 10f, 0f);
upper_limit.setLabelPosition(LimitLine.LimitLabelPosition.RIGHT_TOP);
upper_limit.setTextSize(10f);


LimitLine lower_limit = new LimitLine(mChartData.getYMin(), "Min Value");
lower_limit.setLineWidth(2f);
lower_limit.enableDashedLine(10f, 10f, 0f);
lower_limit.setLabelPosition(LimitLine.LimitLabelPosition.RIGHT_BOTTOM);
lower_limit.setTextSize(10f);

leftAxis.addLimitLine(upper_limit);
leftAxis.addLimitLine(lower_limit);
leftAxis.setDrawLimitLinesBehindData(true);



// set data
holder.chart.setData((LineData) mChartData);

// do not forget to refresh the chart
// holder.chart.invalidate();
holder.chart.animateX(750);

return convertView;
```

Comment: Hello. I found the anwser. I need to put leftAxis.removeAllLimitLines(); before to add a limit because that line code prevent to have limit overlaping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the anwser. I need to put leftAxis.removeAllLimitLines(); before to add a limit because that line code prevent to have limit overlaping –